# How to group similar characters in a string in scala?

Tags: regex, scala

Lets assume I have a string as such:

```
val a = "aaaabbbcccss"
```

and I want to group only the a's and b's as such:

```
"a4b3cccss"
```

I have tries `a.toList.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size)` but that returns a map with no ordering so I cannot convert it into the form I want. I was wondering if there is a function in scala that can achieve what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
val a = "aaaabbbcccss"
val p = """([ab])\1*""".r
println(p replaceAllIn (a, m => s"${m.group(1)}${m.group(0).size}") )
```

See [Scala demo](https://ideone.com/HuIpqA)

The regex matches:

- `([ab])` - Group 1: `a` or `b`
- `\1*` - zero or more occurrences of the char captured into Group 1.

In the replacement part, `m.group(1)` is the char captured into Group 1 and `m.group(0).size` is the size of the whole match.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you might create a function which you can give your string and a list of characters and use a recursive approach where you could take consecutive characters from the list using `takeWhile`.

Then drop from the list using the length of the result from takewhile and add to the accumulator what you want to concatenate to the `acc` string which will be returned when the list will be empty.

```
def countSimilar(str: String, ch: List[Char]): String = {
  def process(l: List[Char], acc: String = ""): String = {
    l match {
      case Nil => acc
      case h :: _ =>
        val tw = l.takeWhile(_ == h)
        acc + process(
          l.drop(tw.length),
          if (ch.contains(h)) h + tw.length.toString else tw.mkString("")
        )
    }
  }

  process(str.toList)
}

println(countSimilar("aaaabbbcccss", List('a', 'b')))
println(countSimilar("aaaabbbcccssaaaabb", List('a', 'b', 'c')))
```

That will give you:

```
a4b3cccss
a4b3c3ssa4b2
```

See the [Scala demo](https://ideone.com/ObOvYU)